# How to disable transient libraries patch update?

Tags: npm, frontend, npm-scripts, npm-package

I want to use @babel/core with fixed version 7.16.7.

But it has dependencies on the `package.json` with

for example:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/types": "^7.16.7"
}
```

After using `npm install`, it installs the latest patch of these libraries.

How can I disable this update and ignore ^ in all my dependencies of dependencies, when I install it in my project. It's important for me to use fixed libs.

Node v14, npm v6